# Not able to delete text in an excel cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with a value in a cell , I am not able to clear the contents of that cell no matter what I try, when I type something new into the cell the text remain at the top of the cell and the new content is added at the bottom.

When I select the cell and look at the formula bar it shoes nothing. I am not able to overlay any objects or even pictures above it, it always shows on top.

I cleared all conditional formatting still its there.

Here is a Screenshot of the text

[image]

This happens when  select the area around the thing plus the mouse pointer turns to a arrow instead of the + sign usually when you are in a worksheet.

[image]

Comment: Export to a CSV.  Look at the file in notepad and see if the text is there.  If it is remove and save file and re-import to excel.  If not.. then some vba is forcing the contents in the cell and preventing its removal.

Comment: @xQbert Did it just now, shows as empty space in .CSV file

Comment: Then it looks like some VBA is adding content to that cell on change.  Press Alt-F11 and look though the VBA code for something which may be setting that cell's value. I'm not sure but perhaps saving a copy of  the document as an XLSX may eliminate the code.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Is it a macro-enabled workbook? Any VBA code? Check Data Validation for that cell. As a workaround - even though I am curious what the problem is - copy everything in another sheet :).

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst, I there are no data validations, if i copy  it does not get copied.

Comment: My guess is there is a Private Sub Worksheet_Change type macro auto updating that cell. As xQbert said, check through your vba using Alt+F11 and check "ThisWorkbook". Search for the string which is appearing in that / those cells, then replace it with "".

Comment: @AMorton1989    There are No macros in the sheet apart from a small one which i coded, plus i saved it in a xlsx format and still it was there so i dont think its a vba code

Comment: Is the cell protected? locked? hidden?

Comment: @Chrismas007 How to know that?

Comment: Try a simple sub that has one line `Range("F1").Value = ""` and see if it errors.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Did it , shows empty

Comment: Does it stay empty?  Did that solve the problem?

Comment: @Chrismas007 , It says empty but i can still see the text on the excel sheet, no that didnt solve it

Comment: @ all , if you are not able to answer something does it automatically qualify as off topic?? ok i will accept this one completely irrelevant answer.

Comment: You haven't posted any of your code you have tried.  Also, it might be helpful to post a link to download the sheet as well.

Comment: @Chrismas007 There are no codes , this is not related to VBA, the sheet is confidential cant share.

Comment: Is the sheet or book protected? http://imgur.com/ykmSZMt

Comment: No , it is not protected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recreate the workbook by saving it as a different format, something like a .CSV file mentioned in the comments. Double verify that only what you want is in that .CSV file using Notepad, Wordpad, Notepad++ or the like, and then import that file into a new spreadsheet. You could also save it as .xlsx, which will remove all macros from the workbook.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then I would wonder if something in Excel would have the same behavior for a new workbook with different data. If a new workbook exhibits the same behavior, then there is some VBA code (or something else) running, if not, then it's something attached to the workbook you're currently using. Narrowing it down helps to solve issues like this one.

If all else fails, you could try using ASAP Utilities to remove the macros from the workbook, if there are any. I also found an article that uses a VBA Macro to remove all other VBA code (http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=93).

Comment: I dont think any VBA code is doing it as i saved it in an .xlsx format